# Deserialize generic maps with jackson from a json containing different occurences for the generic type

Tags: java, json, generics, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize generic maps from a json containing different occurences for the generic type:

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
public class MyList<T> {
    Map<T, String> value;

    public MyList() {

    }

    public MyList(Map<T, String> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Map<T, String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public void setValue(Map<T, String> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }   
}
```

Implmentation 1:

```
public class MyStringList extends MyList<String> {
    public MyStringList() {

    }

    public MyStringList(Map<String, String> value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Implementation 2:

```
public class MyIntegerList extends MyList<Integer> {
    public MyIntegerList() {

    }

    public MyIntegerList(Map<Integer, String> value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

I create a `List<MyList<?>> myList` (containing a MyStringList and a MyIntegerList) and serialize it.

```
List<MyList<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
stringMap.put("1",  "1");
list.add(new MyStringList(stringMap));
Map<Integer, String> integerMap = new HashMap<>();
integerMap.put(1,  "1");
list.add(new MyIntegerList(integerMap));
```

Here is the obtained JSON:

```
[{\"@class\":\"test.MyStringList\",\"value\":{\"1\":\"1\"}},{\"@class\":\"test.MyIntegerList\",\"value\":{\"1\":\"1\"}}]
```

I see that boths keys are "1" and not 1 (because I'm using maps, with Lists it works great).

When deserializing, the keys of the 2 maps have become String :

```
List<MyList<?>> result = new JodaMapper().readValue("[{\"@class\":\"test.MyStringList\",\"value\":{\"1\":\"1\"}},{\"@class\":\"test.MyIntegerList\",\"value\":{\"1\":\"1\"}}]", 
                    new TypeReference<List<MyList<?>>>() {});

MyStringList stringList = (MyStringList)result.get(0);
MyIntegerList integerList = (MyIntegerList)result.get(1);
String s = stringList.getValue().keySet().iterator().next(); // OK
Integer i = integerList.getValue().keySet().iterator().next(); // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Is that a bug of jackson deserializer of did I miss something?

**EDIT:**
The problem was with 2.3.2, and solved in 2.7.3

Comment: Can you show the deserialization code? The `readValue`?

Comment: I added the deserialization code.

Comment: This works correctly (no `ClassCastException`) for with Jackson 2.7.3.

Comment: My mistake, I was using Jackson 2.3.2

Comment: Try upgrading. I think the issue is that Jackson used to consider keys as `String` values no matter what and since generics are erased, it could assign to your `Map` just fine. There might be a way to solve it for 2.3.2 but it might be convoluted. If you can upgrade, I suggest you do.